# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: python json

Tags: python, json

**код**

```
import os, json

ar = []

with open('user_list.txt', encoding = 'utf-8' ) as r:
    for i in r:
        n = i.lower().split('\n')[0]
        if n != '':
            ar.append(n)

with open('user_list.json', 'w', encoding = 'utf-8') as e:
    json.dump(ar, e)
```

**ошибка**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\havra\Desktop\json_crlist.py", line 5, in <module>
    with open('user_list.txt', encoding = 'utf-8' ) as r:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'user_list.txt'
```

*файл с кодом и файл с списком в одной дериктории*

Answer (score -1):

уже решил,

добавил `'r'` после `'user_list.txt'`

```
with open('user_list.txt', 'r', encoding = 'utf-8' ) as r:
```

Comment: open и так по умолчанию открывает файл в режиме `'r'`, так что помогло что-то другое

Comment: знаю что по умолчанию r но на удивление оно и помогло

Comment: Я вам могу гарантировать, что если вы теперь в вашем рабочем варианте уберете `'r'` - все будет так же работать, как и с ним. Вам помогло что-то другое, не добавление `'r'`.

Comment: главное что работает

Comment: Ваше "работает" - на грани суеверия. "После" не означает "вследствие" - то что заработало после того как вы добавили "r" не значит что заработало вследствие этого. Были какие-то другие изменения, вследствие которых заработало, а добавленное "r" никак не повлияло. А это значит, что ответ неправильный.